# C++, MingW, ctime, nanosleep() not found?

Tags: c++, mingw, ctime

I just wanted to use nanosleep() but it seems not to be available in MingW ctime:

```
#include <ctime> //this is what I need, isn't it?
```

How can I use nanosleep on MingW? Thanks.

Comment: You could alternatively see if usleep is in unistd.h

Comment: The code I have uses usleep() already. But I read that nanosleep() is better, so I wanted to use it instead of usleep (all the static analyzers throw warnings and usleep is declared as obsolete and there are also some articles on the web about it).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, MinGW doesn't provide nanosleep().
MinGW only provides functions on [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/634ca0c2) list, which are in the Microsoft API.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Is there another alternative to usleep and nanosleep that works on both, Windows and Linux, without a lot of hacks and is not declared as obsolete?

Comment: Unfortunately not. #ifdef is the best way to go.

Answer (score 1):

In standard C++ library there is no such function (`nanosleep`). 
It is POSIX specific function declared in `<time.h>` not in `<ctime>`. You are under windows. Windows isn't POSIX.
If you want to  use POSIX library you need to install [Cygwin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cygwin).

Comment: Though it *does* claim to be POSIX-compliant (which is an utter lie though)